# Different names - JS and CS

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Im Trying to get to the same text on JS and on CS

JS CODE:

```
var LblSits = document.getElementById('<%=SelectedSits.ClientID%>');

LblSits.textContent+= NumId;
```

CS Code:

```
int Sits = int.Parse(SelectedSits.Text);
```

When i Run This , i can see the `SelectedSits` Label updating with numbers
but when im trying to Debug it from the CS its always empty ("").

the diffrence of the names driving me crazy.
same happened to me With `ImageUrl` on CS and `src` on JS until i figured it out.

Which name connected to whom? 
What can i do?
Why is that always empty?

Comment: you are only modifying it on the client side. you'll need a form/ajax to update the server.

Comment: What can i do with the form?

Comment: the form is the communication channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C# code, you can only see content that is changed in JavaScript code for specific controls that support sending the changes made by JavaScript on the client back to the server.

Instead of using a Label, use a TextBox or HiddenField control.